# Make JSF 1.2 render html radio only with SelectOneRadio instead of table elements

Tags: html, jsf, html-table, renderer

When using `h:selectOneRadio`, JSF is rendering table elements (table, tbody, tr, td) along with it. Is there a way to make JSF render the html radio input and the label only?

I do not want to use tomhawk's layout="spread". 
I want to change such behavior for checkboxes also. I guess the only way is to supply a custom renderer. Can someone please guide me how I can create a custom renderer for this?

Answer (score 1):

Tomahawk is open source. Just look in [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk/tomahawk12/1.1.14/org/apache/myfaces/renderkit/html/ext/HtmlRadioRenderer.java#HtmlRadioRenderer) of Tomahawk's renderer to learn how to create it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You can make this

```
 <input type="radio" name="NomPourToutRadio" value="value" />
```

and recuperate the item selected by

```
String value = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("NomPourToutRadio")
```